# High perfomance key-value store for Java

Tags: java, database

I need to process a high amount of incoming datasets. The data is that simple I can abstract it into a datastructure like

```
HashMap<String, DataClass>
```

Someone knowing a Database that is suitable for the follwing requirements:

1. High performance fetching of the associated value-object by given key
2. Automatic persistence to hard drive (on insert/update)
3. Not affected by the GBC through program life cycle.
4. Not required but cool if so, lightweight

I searched for some in-memory solutions like apache ignite, but can't decide which to take.

Comment: How about Guava's MultiMap?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600780/java-which-database-technologie-to-use-for-a-huge-amount-of-high-frequently-ch?rq=1 ?

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772058/which-embedded-db-written-in-java-for-a-simple-key-value-store?rq=1?

Answer (score 1):

Hazelcast?

It seems you are looking for a distributed hashtable.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into EHCache - it can be deployed in-process or separately if your requirements change.
http://www.ehcache.org/